# Form Validation in external JavaScript File using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My document.getElementById function is returning null on a value I know exists. Specifically I try:

```
//in an external .js file
var UserName = document.getElementById('<%=_username.ClientID%>');
```

And test it using some conditions, which never happen due to the element id value being null. I define _username in a user control file here:

```
...
<fieldset class="login"> 
    <legend class="login">Login</legend>
    <label for="<%=_username.ClientID%>">
        User Name:</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="_username" runat="server" CssClass="login" />
    <label for="<%=_password.ClientID%>">
        Password:</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="_password" runat="server" CssClass="login" TextMode="Password" />
    <br />
    <span class="response">
        <asp:Literal ID="_response" runat="server" /></span>        
    <asp:Button ID="_login" runat="server" Text="Login"/>
</fieldset>
```

I verified my page is listening to the javascript file by testing a simpler function that doesn't require use of getElementById().

Comment: You have asp.net code in a js file? Are js files parsed by asp.net?

Comment: @Musa JS files are not parsed by ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of what you say is true, the problem is most likely that

```
var UserName = document.getElementById('<%=_username.ClientID%>');
```

is getting run before the dom is ready.  Try moving this script down to the very end of your `body` section to ensure the dome is ready before this runs.

ie

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        // rest of script
        var UserName = document.getElementById('<%=_username.ClientID%>');
        // rest of script
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I recall reading a similar response in another thread, but I'm trying to accomplish this with an external script file. I call the src in the head of the HTML; will this still cause DOM issues?

Comment: @Nibirue - not sure about this, but I *think* you might be able to move that script tag down to the end of your body like above.  `<script src=..."</script></body>`

Answer (score 0):

Your title says "external javascript file".  If this is in the external javascript file:

```
var UserName = document.getElementById('<%=_username.ClientID%>');
```

This will not work because `<%= %>` notation does not work in JS files, only ASPX or ASCX.

Comment: This makes sense; what is the alternative then to retrieve the ClientID for _username?

Comment: If you can guarantee it's exactly _username on the client, and not ct100_contentplaceholder__username, then you can just hard-code _username.  Otherwise, you can put the code as it appears above in ASP.NET, and then your script can reference the UserName variable (as long as the script is defined below the creation of the variable).